# 301 Redirects: /article_list.php?parent_cat=152&catid=187??? How Do I Redirect This?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'm setting up 301 Redirects in my .htaccess and 1 of them is:

`Redirect 301 /article_list.php?parent_cat=152&catid=187 http://mysitehere.com/resources/objects/tribulus/`

When I double check it by going to `http://mysitehere.com/article_list.php?parent_cat=152&catid=187` it just stays there on that page and it says 404: Page Not Found.  Did I do this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need mod_rewrite rule to match query string. Consider this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^parent_cat=152&catid=187$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^article_list\.php$ /resources/objects/tribulus/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

**UPDATE:: Your full .htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^parent_cat=152&catid=187$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^article_list\.php$ /resources/objects/tribulus/? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1/ [L]
```

Comment: went to the url `http://mysiteurl.com/article_list.php/parent_cat=152&catid=187` to test and it just adds a trailing slash at the end.. I pasted exactly what you have above any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You are missing `?` in your URI. Should it not be: `http://mysiteurl.com/article_list.php?parent_cat=152&catid=187` ?

Comment: just tried: `http://mysiteurl.com/article_list.php?parent_cat=152&catid=187` and it changed the URL to `http://mysiteurl.com/article_list.php/?parent_cat=152&catid=187` .. I thought it might be the trailing slash enforcement but when I removed that I still have the same results

Comment: Hmm in that case it is due to an existing rule you have in place. Since my suggested rule should redirect to: `/resources/objects/tribulus/` Can you paste your current .htaccess in your question. Also do you have any other .htaccess also?

Comment: there doesnt seemt o be any other .htaccess but ill keep looking.. here is the file: http://d.pr/6pvE  I have to remove the period before "htaccess since the file was invisible and i couldnt see it on the desktop

Comment: Checked your `.htaccess` and it is indeed problematic. See updated answer with your full .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `Redirect` directive of the `mod_alias` module doesn't really handle/match query strings at all, cf. its documentation:

> [`mod_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) is designed to handle simple URL manipulation tasks. For more
>      complicated tasks such as manipulating the query string, use the tools provided
>      by [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

For matching a query string, I suggest you use a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)+[`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) combination, where the `RewriteCond` matches your `%{QUERY_STRING}` lexicographically. :)

Comment: could you show me an example using what I have above? I'm new to redirects so I don't have any idea what this stuff means to be honest